# Github not reading fonts embedded in site

Tags: css, github

I've design this site, and have used a font, embedded it within the site, it reads fine on my computer, but when I look at the site on another computer, the font does not appear?

Any idea how to fix it? Thanks:)

website: http://schan01.github.io/project2/hypertext.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to have that font file uploaded somewhere. most

`url('//fonts/Apercu.otf')` is telling the browser to look at `http://fonts/Apercu.otf` which is obviously not correct.

Comment: can i upload it on github? sorry i'm pretty new to this

Comment: @user3757075 I would assume you can upload it in the same spot as your html file and then reference it with a relative path.